# how to use Helper::validateLuhn($cardnumber) in omnipay

Tags: omnipay

i have developed paypal pro by using omnipay.And i need to do card validation before payment process start.

Helper::validateLuhn($cardnumber)

But i am getting error like this:- Fatal error: Class 'Helper' not found

What is the reason for getting this error?Need to include any other file?Any help?

Comment: Are you loading Omnipay Via composer? Did you require the vendor/autoload.php? Are you using a `use` statement at the top of your file to include the Helper class?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the Helper::validateLuhn() function, you need to add this to your php file:

```
use Omnipay\Common\Helper;
```